# help me find inequality

Tags: inequality

If $a+2b>3$   and $b+3c>5$ then $a+b+c> \hspace{.1cm} ?$

Comment: Are $a, b, c > 0$?

Comment: Are you looking for any answer or the greatest $?$ that makes this true?

Answer (score 7):

***If*** $a > 0$, you have $a + b + c > \frac{8}{3}$.

This is since you have
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{3} \left( a + 2b \right) + \frac{1}{3} \left( b + 3c \right) + \frac{2}{3}a}_{=a + b + c} > \underbrace{\frac{1}{3} 3 + \frac{1}{3} 5 + \frac{2}{3} 0}_{=\frac{8}{3}}$$

I.e. you take $\frac{1}{3}$ of your first inequality, $\frac{1}{3}$ of your second inequality and $\frac{2}{3}$ of the inequality $a > 0$ and add them together.

One might ask oneself if one can add the condition $b > 0$ *instead* of $a > 0$ and if one can get a solution then. The answer is no: You can set $a = -N$ for some positive $N$, and then $b = \frac{N}{2} + 2$, so the first inequality is satisfied:
$$a + 2b = -N + 2 \left( \frac{N}{2} + 2 \right) = 4 > 3$$
and set $c = 2$ so the second inequality is always satisfied. We then have
$$a + b + c = -N + \frac{N}{2} + 2 + 2 = -\frac{N}{2} + 4$$
so $a + b + c$ can be made arbitrarily small.

You can do the same for the inequality $c > 0$, using the same values as above. You can also note that the same values handle the case $b,c > 0$.

### Possible alternatives

However, $a > 0$ is not the only (but maybe the most "natural") inequality one can add to make the problem solvable; another possibility is $a > k$ for some $k$.

A less trivial inequality is $a + c > k$, in which case we have
$$a + b + c > 2 + \frac{4}{7}k.$$

Comment: You can also show that $\frac83$ is optimal: take $(a,b,c) = (\epsilon, \frac32+\epsilon, \frac76+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 4):

The data you gave isn't enough! In fact, we have to find a linear combination of $a+2b$ and $b+3c$ that gives $a+b+c$. So let $\alpha ,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such as $\alpha (a+2b)+\beta(b+3c)=a+b+c$. Thus $\alpha a+(2\alpha+\beta)b+3\beta c=a+b+c$. Since $a$, $b$ and $c$ are linearly independent because nothing in your assumption shows the oposite then we must have $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{3}$ and $2\alpha +\beta=1$ which isn't true.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a=-1,000,000$, $b=500,003$, and $c=0$.  Then both of your inequalities are satisfied since $a+2b = -1,000,000 + 500,003+500,003=6>3$ and $b+3c=500,003+0>5$

However, note that $a+b+c=-1,000,000+500,003+0=-499,997$

Convince yourself that if we were to have multiplied all of $a,b,c$ by the same amount (positive and greater than 1), it will still satisfy your equations, say for example $a\mapsto 1000 a = -1,000,000,000$, $b\mapsto 1000b = 500,000,300$, and $c\mapsto 1000c=0$.  In doing so, the inequalities are still satisfied, but our lowerbound on $a+b+c$ has decreased even more.

There is thus no lower bound on $a+b+c$

Answer (score 3):

$m(a+2b) + n(b+3c) = p(a+b+c) \to ma + 2mb+nb+3nc = pa + pb + pc \to m = p, 2m+n = p, 3n = p \to p = m = 3n $. This leads to $p = 0$, which means as @Scientifica pointed out that you have not enough info to conclude.

Comment: Indeed! And check out JMoravitz' answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+2b=3+d$ and $b+3c=5+e$ and $a+b+c=x$. This has a solution in $a,b,c$ for any$d,e,x$. So $x$ can be any value. Did you omit some condition?